# bash menu script exit

Tags: bash, menu

I am writing a menu.
This is the script I have.
when I type q it dose not echo "done"
what I need to change in the script to get it to echo "done"?

```
#!/bin/bash
rap '' 2
while true
do
    clear
    echo  "=============================="
    echo  "menu"
    echo  "=============================="
    echo  "Enter 1 to for option 1t: "
    echo  "Enter q to exit:"
    echo -e "\n"
    echo -e "Enter your selection"
    read answer
    case "$answer" in
        1) echo "option 1"
            echo "Option 1"
            done;;  
        q) exit 
           echo "done" ;;
    esac
    echo -e "Enter return to continue \c"
    read input
done
exit 0
```

Comment: `select x in "Enter 1 to for option 1t" "Enter 2 to exit"; do echo $x; [[ $x == "Enter 2 to exit" ]] && break; done`

Comment: would i add && break; done instead of echo "done" ;;

Answer (score 0):

there were some minor bugs in your code. 1) case does must not have done. 2) exit before calling echo does not make sense.

```
while true; do
    clear
    echo  "=============================="
    echo  "menu"
    echo  "=============================="
    echo  "Enter 1 to for option 1t: "
    echo  "Enter q to exit:"
    echo -e "\n"
    echo -e "Enter your selection"
    read answer
    case "$answer" in
         1) echo "option 1"
            echo "Option 1";;
         q) echo "done"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
    echo -e "Enter return to continue \c"
    read input
done
exit 0
```